# Can gluten-free flour be cooked and eaten as a hot breakfast cereal?

Tags: flour, gluten-free

I'm talking about single flours, such as quinoa flour, amaranth flour, and buckwheat flour, not flour blends or hot cereal mixes.

Comment: Are you asking if it's healthy (we don't answer that here), if it's tasty (very subjective), or something else?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it. It will taste more like a pudding (not necessarily wheat pudding) than like a cereal. The consistency will depend on the grind size, and can get down to standard starch pudding, or be a bit gritty like semolina pudding.

Most people won't find the taste of a pure flour + water or even flour + milk pudding interesting enough, so you can experiment adding stuff to it. You're only limited by your own imagination.

Comment: Would the proportions of water and flour be the same as the proportions of water and grain, were I preparing the same amount of whole-grains? In other words, should the amount of water and quinoa flour be the same as if I was boiling regular quinoa? Should the proportions of water and buckwheat flour be the same as if I was boiling regular buckwheat groats?

Comment: That's a separate question to be asked on its own, and I'm not even sure that it is the same for all grains. In any case, you'll have to specify what end results you want when you ask for the ratio.

Answer (score 1):

Yes definitely you can use flour as a breakfast dish. All you need to do is, dry roast the flour a little bit keeping in mind not to burn it. Perfectly roasted flour emanates a special smell(aroma) which is a bit sweet. Thereafter add some water to the flour to make a slurry out of it, alongside you can add some fried potatoes or leftover hash-browns with fried spinach or anything you like which is cooked al dente(just a suggestion) and blend them in the flour(slurry). I'd suggest, cook the slurry for a bit till it reaches the desired form where everything is perfectly blended and in perfect harmony. There you have a nutritious breakfast!

Comment: The question specifically speaks of gluten-free flour but your answer does not address this. Would this method work for **all** types of flour?

Comment: @Catija flour mentioned in the answer means gluten-free flour. I have just given a few pointers on "how to" handle flour in the best way possible. My guess is, you can pretty much use any flour at hand to make a slurry(gravy) and add accompaniments of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

I do lightly brown my gluten free flour, brown rice, sorghum, and millet are my favorites. Then make a slurry as the first answer suggested. The amount of flour to water (or milk) ratio depends on the flour and how thick you like your porridge. Personally I found brown rice to be 2-3Tbsp of browned flour to 1 cup of water, but some of the other flours take more. We like to sweeten ours after it is cooked with a little honey (brown sugar would also work) or your sweetener of choice.